# particle system for cloud or smoke

Tags: opengl, cuda, particle-system

I am trying to make a simple particle system for cloud and smoke simulation using OpenGL and CUDA.

How can I make the particles in the particle system behave as a real cloud or smoke would behave in some low turbulent winds?

Some problems I'm having right now is:

1. The particles clump together in a big ball
2. The particles spread away into infinity
3. The particles suddenly slingshot themselves away.

**I've already done the rendering** of the particles so I'm satisfied in that area.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The little grasshopper has some fantastic tutorials on particle systems of this nature: [Noise Based Particles](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=63) (smoke), [Noise Based Particles II](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=67) (smoke), [Simple Fluid Simulation](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=58) (smoke), and [Deep Opacity Maps](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=69) (clouds). Most of these are purely OpenGL but the overall techniques could be applied in CUDA / OpenGL interops if you so desired.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Android ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should study the Reynolds Boids, it will provide you some ideas to avoid those problems:

http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/