# GLSL shader for texture 'smoke' effect

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I've looked around and haven't found anything relevant. I'm tyring to create a shader to give a texture smoke effect animation like here:

[image: example]

Not asking for a complete/full solution (although that would be awesome) but any pointers towards where I can get started to achieve this effect. Would i need to have the vertices for the drawing or is this possible if I have the texture only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example pictured it appears as if they have the vertices. Possibly the "drawing" of the flower shape was recorded and then played back continuously. Then the effect hits the vertices based on a time offset from when they were drawn. The effect there appears to mostly be a motion blur.

So to replicate this effect you would need the vertices. See how the top of the flower starts to disappear before the bottom? If you look closely you'll see that actually the blur effect timing follows the path of the flower around counter clockwise. Even on the first frame of your gif you can see that the end of the flower shape is a brighter yellow than the beginning.

The angle of the motion blur also appears to change over time from being more left oriented to being more up oriented.

And the brightness of the segment is also changing over time starting with the yellowish color and ending either black or transparent.

What I can't tell from this is if the effect is additive, meaning that they're applying the effect to the whole frame and then to the results of that effect each frame, or if it's being recreated each frame.  If recreated each frame you'd be able to do the effect in reverse and have the image appear.

If you are wanting this effect on a bitmapped texture instead of a line object that's also doable, although the approach would be different.

Let's start with the line object and assume you have the vertices. The way I would approach it is that I would add a percentage of decay as an attribute to the vertex data. Then each frame that you render you'd first update the decay percentage based on the time for that vertex. Stagger them slightly.

Then the shader would draw the line segment using a motion blur shader where the amount of motion blur, the angle of the blur, and the color of the segment are controlled by a varying variable that is assigned by the decay attribute. I haven't tested this shader. Treat it like pseudocode. But I'd approach it this way...  Vertex Shader:

```
 uniform mat4 u_modelViewProjectionMatrix;
 uniform float maxBlurSizeConstant;  // experiment with value and it will be based on the scale of the render

 attribute vec3 a_vertexPosition;
 attribute vec2 a_vertexTexCoord0;
 attribute float a_decay;

 varying float v_decay;
 varying vec2 v_fragmentTexCoord0;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord1;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord2;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord3;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord4;
 varying vec2 v_texCoordM1;
 varying vec2 v_texCoordM2;
 varying vec2 v_texCoordM3;
 varying vec2 v_texCoordM4;

 void main()
 {
    gl_Position = u_modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(a_vertexPosition,1.0);

    v_decay = a_decay;

    float angle = 2.8 - a_decay * 0.8;  // just an example of angles

    vec2 tOffset = vec2(cos(angle),sin(angle)) * maxBlurSizeConstant * a_decay;

    v_fragmentTexCoord0 = a_vertexTexCoord0;

    v_texCoordM1 = a_vertexTexCoord0 - tOffset;
    v_texCoordM2 = a_vertexTexCoord0 - 2.0 * tOffset;
    v_texCoordM3 = a_vertexTexCoord0 - 3.0 * tOffset;
    v_texCoordM4 = a_vertexTexCoord0 - 4.0 * tOffset;
    v_texCoord1 = a_vertexTexCoord0 + tOffset;
    v_texCoord2 = a_vertexTexCoord0 + 2.0 * tOffset;
    v_texCoord3 = a_vertexTexCoord0 + 3.0 * tOffset;
    v_texCoord4 = a_vertexTexCoord0 + 4.0 * tOffset;
 }
```

Fragment Shader:

```
 uniform sampler2D u_textureSampler;

 varying float v_decay;
 varying vec2 v_fragmentTexCoord0;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord1;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord2;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord3;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord4;
 varying vec2 v_texCoordM1;
 varying vec2 v_texCoordM2;
 varying vec2 v_texCoordM3;
 varying vec2 v_texCoordM4;

 void main()
 {
     lowp vec4 fragmentColor = texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_fragmentTexCoord0) * 0.18;

     fragmentColor += texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_texCoordM1) * 0.15;
     fragmentColor += texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_texCoordM2) * 0.12;
     fragmentColor += texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_texCoordM3) * 0.09;
     fragmentColor += texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_texCoordM4) * 0.05;
     fragmentColor += texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_texCoord1) * 0.15;
     fragmentColor += texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_texCoord2) * 0.12;
     fragmentColor += texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_texCoord3) * 0.09;
     fragmentColor += texture2D(u_textureSampler, v_texCoord4) * 0.05;

     gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor.rgb, fragmentColor.a * v_decay);
 }
```

Of course the trick is in varying the decay amount per vertex based on a slight offset in time.

If you want to do the same with a sprite you're going to do something very similar except that the difference between the decay per vertex would have to be played with to get right as there are only 4 vertices.

**SORRY - EDIT**

Sorry... The above shader blurs the incoming texture. It doesn't necessarily blur the color of the line being drawn. This might or might not be what you want to do.  But again without knowing more of what you are actually trying to accomplish it's difficult to give you a perfect answer. I get the feeling you'd rather do this on a sprite anyway than a line vertex based object.  So no you can't copy and paste this shader in to your code as is. But it shows the concept of how you'd do what you're looking to do. Especially if you're doing it on a texture instead of on a vertex based line.

Also the above shader isn't complete. For example it doesn't expand to allow the blur to get beyond the bounds of the texture. And it gets texture info from outside the area where the sprite is in the sprite sheet. To fix this you'd have to start with a bounding box larger than the sprite and shrink the sprite in the vertex to be the right size. And you'd have to not grab textels from the spite sheet beyond the bounds of the sprite.  There are ways of doing this without having to include a bunch of white space around the sprite in the sprite sheet.

**Update**

On second look it might be particle based.  If it is they again have all the vertices but as particle locations.  I sort of prefer the idea that it's line segments because I don't see any gaps. So if it is particles there are a lot and they're tightly placed. The particles are still decaying cascading from the top petal around to the last. Even if it's line segments you could treat the vertices as particles to apply the wind and gravity.

As for how the smoke effect works check out this helper app by 71 squared: https://71squared.com/particledesigner

The way it works is that you buy the Mac app to use to design and save your particle. Then you go to their github and get the iOS code. But this particular code creates a particle emitter. Doing a shape out of particles would be different code. But the evolution of the particles is the same.

Comment: Another way might be to use particles and make the flower shape out of particles but I don't believe that's how this one was done. But of course you could do a smoke effect like this with animated particles.  Also no offense to anyone but don't listen to those who downplays the capabilities of ES. The more recent iPhones have very powerful graphic chip. I've done some really cool effects. This exact thing can easily be done on the iPhone.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. Haven't had a chance to go over your answer in detail yet, will do when I get back today. But yes, I have the vertices. This is basically a drawing (touch screen) and I record the vertices and estimate the curve using cubic bezier and approximate the curve. What do you recommend in this case then (knowing that I do have the vertices)?

Comment: Just an update. Turns out you are correct. It is a particle system. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10):

Modelling smoke with a fluid simulation isn't simple and can be very slow for a detailed simulation. Using noise to add finer details can be a fair bit faster. If this is the direction you want to head in, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529982/1888983) answer has some good links to [the little grasshopper](http://prideout.net/blog/). If you have a texture, use it to initialize the smoke density (or spawn particles for that matter) and run the simulation. If you start with vector data, and want the animation to trail along the curve as in your example it gets more complex. Perhaps draw the curve over the top of the smoke simulation, gradually drawing less of it and drawing the erased bits as density into the simulation. Spawning particles along its length and using "noise based particles" as linked above sounds like a good alternative too.

Still, it sounds like you're after something a bit simpler. I've created a short demo on shadertoy, just using perlin noise for animated turbulence on a texture. It doesn't require any intermediate texture storage or state information other than a global time.

[https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mtf3R7
[image]](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mtf3R7)

The idea started with trying to create streaks of smoke that blur and grow with time. Start with a curve, sum/average colour along it and then make it longer to make the smoke appear to move. Rather than add points to the curve over time to make it longer, the curve has a fixed number of points and their distance increases with time.

To create a random curve, perlin noise is sampled recursively, providing offsets to each point in turn.

[image]

Using mipmapping, the samples towards the end of the curve can cover a larger area and make the smoke appear to blur into nothing, just as your image does. However, since this is a gather operation the end of the smoke curve is actually the start (hence the `steps-i` below).

```
//p = uv coord, o = random offset for per-pixel noise variation, t = time
vec3 smoke(vec2 p, vec2 o, float t)
{
    const int steps = 10;
    vec3 col = vec3(0.0);
    for (int i = 1; i < steps; ++i)
    {
        //step along a random path that grows in size with time
        p += perlin(p + o) * t * 0.002;
        p.y -= t * 0.003; //drift upwards

        //sample colour at each point, using mipmaps for blur
        col += texCol(p, float(steps-i) * t * 0.3);
    }
    return col.xyz / float(steps);
}
```

As always with these effects, you can spend hours playing with constants getting it to look that tiny bit better. I've used a linearly changing value for the mipmap bias as the second argument to `texCol()`, which I'm sure could be improved. Also averaging a number of `smoke()` calls with varying `o` will give a smoother result.

[*EDIT*] If you want the smoke to animate along a curve with this method, I'd use a second texture that stores a "time offset" to delay the simulation for certain pixels. Then draw the curve with a gradient along it so the end of the curve will take a little while to start animating. Since it's a gather operation you should draw a *much* fatter lines into this time offset texture as it's the pixels around them which will gather colour. Unfortunately this will break when parts of the curve are too close or intersect.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL **ES** suggests that your target platform may not have the computional power to do a real smoke simulation (and if it does, it would consume quite a bit of power, which is undesirable on a device like a phone).

However, your target device will definitively have the power to create a fake texture-space effect which looks good enough to be convincing.

First look at the animation you posted. The flower is blurring and fading, there is a sideway motion to the left ("wind") and an upwards motion of the smoke. Thus, what is primarily needed is ping-ponging between two textures, sampling for each fragment at the fragment's location offset by a vector pointing *downwards and right* (you only have *gather* available, not *scatter*).
No `texelFetchOffset` or such function in ES 2.0 so you'll have to use plain old `texture2D` and do the vector add yourself, but that shouldn't be a lot of trouble. Note that since you need to use `texture2D` anyway you'll not need to worry about `gl_FragCoord` either. Have the interpolator give you the correct texture coordinate (simply set texcoord of vertices of the quad to 0 on one end, and to 1 on the other end).

To get the blur effect, randomize the offset vector (e.g. by adding another random vector with a much smaller magnitude, so the "overall direction" remains the same), to get the fade effect either multiply alpha with an attenuation factor (such as 0.95) or do the same with the color (which will give you "black" rather than "transparent", but depending on wheter or not you want premultiplied alpha, that may be the correct thing).

Alternatively you could implement the blur and fade effect by generating mipmaps first (gradually fade them to transparent), and using the optional `bias` value in `texture2D`, slightly increasing the bias as time progresses. That will be, yet lower quality (possibly with visible box artefacts), but it allows you to preprocess much of the calculation ahead of time and has a *much* more cache-friendly access pattern.